# Algorithm Design - Modify a polygon so that all its lines are at a multiple of k degrees, maximizing Intersection Over Union

Tags: geometry, algorithms, polygons

I've been trying for a while to think of an algorithm as follows:

Input: List of line segments (x1,y1,x2,y2) forming a closed polygon. x/y points need not be integers, polygon need not be convex.

Output: Another list of line segments forming a closed polygon, with the property that:

a) Relative to the horizontal every line segment is exactly a multiple of k degrees - i.e. if k=60 then there are only 6 possible angles a line could take.

b) Intersection Over Union between the output polygon and the input polygon is maximized.

---

The greedy algorithm would be:

For each line segment, rotate it about its midpoint to align it to the nearest multiple of k degrees, changing the start/end point of neighboring lines to keep the polygon closed.

Choose the line segment not yet aligned for which making this alignment causes the highest IOU relative to previous iteration, and commit to that move.

Repeat until all lines adjusted.

---

However, I don't think this would produce the best possible result - when trying to change a line whose endpoints have already been changed by moving other lines, it might not produce an answer as good as an algorithm that considered all the lines together.

1) Does the greedy algorithm produce the optimal answer? (I expect not)

2) Can you help me devise an algorithm that does produce the optimal answer?

Comment: Is there something else to this problem, like "you are only allowed to rotate and translate the line segments but not stretch them" ?  Also it is ambiguous whether k is an input or something you can choose.

Comment: So, if your input is 5 line segments, why not just output a regular pentagon large enough to hold the input polygon?

Comment: Also if this come from an online source, you should link it for attribution and clarity.

Comment: The goal is to maximize Intersection Over Union - that is, the area of the intersection of the two polygons divided by the union of the area of the two polygons. That's why a much larger pentagon won't work. There is nothing else to the problem, the lines can move any which way. It's not from an online source, I'm trying to develop this for a computer vision application.

Comment: I would suggest looking at a simple example first, to get some idea of the difficulties involved. Let the original polygon be an equilateral triangle, let $k=90$, so the new polygon should be an axis-aligned rectangle – how would you maximize your area ratio in this very special case? If that's too hard a problem, then there's no hope for your question.

Comment: @J.Doe Ok I see.  This is a mixed combinatorial-real number problem.  You want to create an equation f(z) where z is n+2 real numbers (for example, 2 for where a center point is and n for distance of the edges to the center) and f is the area you get as a result of choice of z.  Then you want to convert it to a formula that is like $$f(z) = \begin{cases} case 1 &  f_1(z) \\ case 2 & f_2(z) \\ \vdots \end{cases}$$ to make it a combination of real number formulas $f_j$ .  Then it becomes a problem of maximizing each $f_j$, which is just a multivariable calculus problem, ....

Comment: ... because each $f_j$ is $\mathbb R^{n+2} \to \mathbb R$ with no boolean logic in it. 
 The main challenge will be minimizing the number of cases to sub exponential.  This is a monster of a question that almost begs for computer algebra assistance.  (actually it occurs to me that determining how many edges the output polygon has (n) is also going to be difficult to determine, not sure how to do that other than trial and error).

Comment: Btw this problem would probably get better attention at cs.stackexchange.com and if you can restrict this to convex shapes you probably should.

Comment: So, J.D, have you had a look at a simple case, as I recommended?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.